# How to print spesific string/char variable from different function

Tags: c++, string, function, char

```
void nama_barang(){
    char barang1[35] = "ORICO 4 Port Usb Hub 3.0";
    char barang2[35] = "ORICO 7 Port USB Hub 3.0";
    char barang3[35] = "ORICO 3 Port Charger 65W Type C";
    char barang4[35] = "ORICO USB 2.0 Micro B 1.5M";
    char barang5[35] = "ORICO USB 3.1 Type C 1.5M0";
    char barang6[35] = "Vention Kabel HDMI v2.0 1M";
    char barang7[35] = "Vention Kabel HDMI v2.0 2M";
    char barang8[35] = "Keyboard Votre KB2308 USB";
    char barang9[35] = "Uticon Stop Kontak 6 lubang";
    char barang10[35] = "Samsung SSD 860 EVO 250 GB";
}

int main(){

}
```

how do i print barang 1 inside a int main(), and should i change to string/char instead of void?

Comment: What do your function do? If it's just to store data, probably should use a `struct`.

Comment: Local variables can't be accessed outside the block they are defined. You may either return a value from the function, or define them as global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've not given any specific problem to solve except that you want to just print variable `barang1` through `main()`, this is how you print :

**Version 1**: Print a single variable by returning it by value

```
#include <iostream>

//return type is std::string now instead of char or void
std::string nama_barang(){
    std::string barang1 = "ORICO 4 Port Usb Hub 3.0";
    std::string barang2 = "ORICO 7 Port USB Hub 3.0";
    std::string barang3 = "ORICO 3 Port std::stringger 65W Type C";
    //similarly other code below
    
    //return whatever you want to print 
    return barang1;
}

int main(){
    //call the function and use its return value 
    std::cout << nama_barang() <<std::endl;
}
```

In the above call to `name_barang` function, it will return a `std::string` type variable **by value** which is printed onto the console.

**Version 2**: Return a `std::vector` and use it to print whatever you want

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
std::vector<std::string> nama_barang(){
    std::vector<std::string> myVector{"ORICO 4 Port Usb Hub 3.0", 
    "ORICO 7 Port USB Hub 3.0","ORICO 3 Port std::stringger 65W Type C",
    "ORICO USB 2.0 Micro B 1.5M","ORICO USB 3.1 Type C 1.5M0",
    "Vention Kabel HDMI v2.0 1M","Vention Kabel HDMI v2.0 2M",
    "Keyboard Votre KB2308 USB","Uticon Stop Kontak 6 lubang",
    "Samsung SSD 860 EVO 250 GB"};
    
    //do some processing with the above vector if you need 

    
    //return the whole vector by value 
    return myVector;
}

int main(){
    //print the first element of the returned vector 
   std::cout << nama_barang()[0] <<std::endl;
   
   //print the second element of the returned vector 
   std::cout << nama_barang()[1] << std::endl;
}
```

You can also use a `struct` or a `class` to store variables and then return that instance of the `struct`. The above examples are just to give you an idea of how you might do what you want.